# Is it possible to get DOI from ISBN of a book?

Tags: books, doi

I need DOI number of the book with ISBN 9780723437512. There is a kindle edition so it should have some electronic identification.

---

How can you get DOI from ISBN?

Comment: To get it from scihub?

Answer (score 18):

[DOI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier) and [ISBN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number) are two different identification numbers and can not be translated into each other. A (digital) book need not have a DOI number, and e.g. a journal article that has a DOI need not have an ISBN number.

If you want to look up whether a book (or journal article, etc.) has a DOI, you can query it at http://www.crossref.org/guestquery

Comment: Thank you for the link! You can do the search with ISBN and first author name. No DOI found for the ISBN here.

Answer (score 13):

Yes DOI and ISBN are separate. However there is apparently a way to get the DOI from the ISBN-A number which is described at this link: https://www.doi.org/factsheets/ISBN-A.html

Note: the ISBN-A means actionable ISBN so they are deriving some properties from the DOI. See https://www.isbn-international.org/content/other-identifiers for more details

---

Syntax of ISBN-A

The ISBN-A is constructed by incorporating an ISBN into the allowed DOI syntax:

Example: 10.978.12345/99990

The syntax specification, reading from left to right, is:

Handle System DOI name prefix = "10."
ISBN (GS1) Bookland prefix = "978." or "979."
ISBN registration group element and publisher prefix = variable length numeric string of 2 to 8 digits
Prefix/suffix divider = "/"
ISBN Title enumerator and checkdigit = maximum 6 digit title enumerator and 1 digit check digit.

---

The DOI website would inform you if

> The ISBN-A you are attempting to resolve has not yet been registered although there may be a corresponding ISBN. To find out about how to register ISBN-As, click here.

and 'here' is the ISBN website given above.

Comment: Can you get a confirmation for the apparent way to get DOI from ISBN-A?

Answer (score 8):

For some special publishers, there is a relation between DOI and ISBN. For example Cambridge University Press’s online books have the format:

> 10.1017/CBO[13 digit ISBN]

Of course, if your publisher doesn’t have an equivalent or you cannot find it, that’s the end of the line ...